# How to specify spearman rank correlation as a loss function in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I wanted to write a loss function that maximizes the spearman rank correlation between two vectors in keras. Unfortunately I could not find an existing implementation, nor a good method to calculate the rank of a vector in keras, so that I could use the formula to implement it myself

```
def rank_correlation(y_true, y_pred):
    pass

model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential()
#### More model code
model.compile(loss=rank_correlation)
```

Can anyone please help me implement *rank_correlation* ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like as follows, [referenced](https://www.kaggle.com/c/google-quest-challenge/discussion/126778).

```
from scipy.stats import spearmanr
def compute_spearmanr(y, y_pred):
    spearsum = 0
    cnt = 0 
    for col in range(y_pred.shape[1]):
        v = spearmanr(y_pred[:,col], y[:,col]).correlation
        if np.isnan(v):
            continue
        spearsum += v
        cnt += 1
    res = spearsum / cnt
    return res

a = np.array([[2., 1., 2., 3.],[3., 3., 4., 5.]] )
b = np.array([[1., 0., 0., 3.], [1., 0., 3., 3.]])
compute_spearmanr(a, b) 
0.9999999999999999
```